# Form is not getting submitted in wordpress:

Tags: wordpress

I have a form which I have created to use as an options page for my plugin settings.
However when I submit the form , It is not getting submitted.

The code for my form is as below

```
<div class="wrap">
<?php echo "<h2>"._('My Plugin Options')."</h2";?>
<form name="my_plugin_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_hidden" value="Y"> 
    <?php echo "<h4>"._('Image Dispaly Options')."</h4>";?>
    <p><?php _e("Image Height: " ); ?><input type="text" name="img_height" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" size="20"></p>
    <p><?php _e("Image Width: " ); ?><input type="text" name="img_width" value="<?php echo $width; ?>" size="20"></p>

    <p class="submit">  
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Update Options') ?>" />  
    </p>  
</form>
```

The code for processing the form have also written in the same page.

If you know the solution, please share it with me. I am a beginner in wordpress plugin developement.

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?php echo "<h2>".__('My Plugin Options')."</h2";?>
    <form name="my_plugin_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_hidden" value="Y"> 
    <?php echo "<h4>".__('Image Dispaly Options')."</h4>";?>
    <p><?php echo __("Image Height: " ); ?><input type="text" name="img_height" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" size="20"></p>
    <p><?php echo __("Image Width: " ); ?><input type="text" name="img_width" value="<?php echo $width; ?>" size="20"></p>

    <p class="submit">  
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Update Options') ?>" />  
    </p>  
</form>
```